# Can ListView Typecasted into TextView?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Can  ListView be type casted into TextView in android studio?

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must add constructor to your WordAdapter, because you have compilation error on that class

Comment: I have added constructor to ,my WordAdpater,then also it is showing like that.

Comment: @pranavsureshsuresh could you show me your WordAdapter with constructor.